# make video from image file using ffmpeg

Tags: image, ubuntu, ffmpeg, video-processing

i have 64 images sequence and i want to make a video using that images.

you can download the images [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8-PxJNlaYSPLXdXcG9qNU9KQlU/edit?usp=sharing)

i use ffmpeg in ubuntu.
here's my command

```
ffmpeg -r 60 -f image2 -s 1360x768 -i "/home/roylisto/Documents/Tugas Akhir/JAva version/UAVSystem/UAVSystem/tmp/result%d.png" -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 "/home/roylisto/Documents/Tugas Akhir/JAva version/UAVSystem/UAVSystem/render/test.mp4"
```

it works but only 39 images has generated to a video. My question is why ffmpeg not render all images in that folder into a video, what is my mistake and how to solve it?

Output Command :

```
    ffmpeg version 2.2.git-73d820e Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 16 2014 10:08:12 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab --enable-libpulse --enable-libx264 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr
  libavutil      52. 89.100 / 52. 89.100
  libavcodec     55. 66.101 / 55. 66.101
  libavformat    55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libavresample   1.  3.  0 /  1.  3.  0
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, image2, from '/home/roylisto/Documents/Tugas Akhir/JAva version/UAVSystem/UAVSystem/tmp/result%d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.62, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 320x240, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
No pixel format specified, yuv444p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.1 Cache64
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 2.1, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] 264 - core 142 r2431 ac76440 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=20.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/home/roylisto/Documents/Tugas Akhir/JAva version/UAVSystem/UAVSystem/render/test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.43.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv444p, 320x240, q=-1--1, 60 fps, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc55.66.101 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:320x240 fmt:rgb24 to size:480x360 fmt:rgb24
frame=   35 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      18kB time=00:00:00.55 bitrate= 264.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=2    
video:17kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 7.355630%
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] frame I:1     Avg QP:14.45  size:  1829
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] frame P:12    Avg QP:20.02  size:   908
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] frame B:22    Avg QP:24.15  size:   161
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] consecutive B-frames: 14.3%  5.7%  0.0% 80.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] mb I  I16..4:  3.3% 84.3% 12.3%
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] mb P  I16..4:  0.6%  2.9%  1.9%  P16..4:  7.6%  6.0%  2.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:78.3%
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 10.1%  3.2%  0.5%  direct: 0.3%  skip:85.8%  L0:36.3% L1:56.4% BI: 7.3%
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] 8x8 transform intra:72.3% inter:49.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] coded y,u,v intra: 34.4% 16.0% 10.7% inter: 3.6% 0.5% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 76% 21%  3%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 14% 22% 50%  2%  2%  1%  5%  2%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  7% 30% 32%  2%  8%  3% 11%  3%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] ref P L0: 64.9% 22.6%  9.7%  2.8%
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] ref B L0: 86.1% 12.2%  1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] ref B L1: 94.3%  5.7%
[libx264 @ 0x2bccce0] kb/s:223.06
```

Comment: Show us the complete, uncut command line output, please.

Comment: @slhck okay , i put it above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the difference here?

```
$ gm identify tmp/result38.png
tmp/result38.png PNG 480x360+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 77.3K 0.000u 0:01

$ gm identify tmp/result39.png
tmp/result39.png PNG 640x480+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 78.3K 0.000u 0:01
```

ffmpeg requires that your images have the exact same dimensions.

To fix the problem install imagemagick (or graphicsmagick, which I prefer for MANY reasons)

and write:

```
# graphicsmagick
gm mogrify -size 480x360 tmp/*.png

# imagemagick
mogrify -size 480x360 tmp/*.png
```

At any rate, your ffmpeg command could be quite a bit more robust. (In fact, you called the rescaling too soon.) here is my ffmpeg recommendation for you:

```
ffmpeg -threads 0 -loglevel error -y -ar 48000 -ac 2 -f s16le -i /dev/zero \
-r 25/1 -f image2 -i "tmp/result%2d.png" -start_number 1 \ 
-c:a libfdk_aac -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=fps=25,format=pix_fmts=yuv420p" \
-s 1360x768 -crf 20 -shortest -vframes 64 "tmp/test.mp4"
```

Here is a breakdown:

You should have an audio track in your h264 file, because otherwise some syncing approaches on a variety of devices (e.g. arm) might not work and your playback rate will be mucked up.

I am not sure if it is just an old habit, but I have always put the -r 25/1 for -f image. Maybe that's just a thing one had to do but is no longer necessary...

You probably shouldn't start with a %d file-number that is 0, I always prefer to use padded numbers. (%2d = 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10...) Linux usually gets it right, but other OS's will probably botch the sequence in the folder listings. If you "can't" rename the result0.png file, you could try adding the "-start_number 0" flag

It is a good idea to explicitly name the playback speed as in the -vf group.

If you don't switch the pixel encoding to yuv420p, then most non-linux systems **will not**
play the file.

The "-shortest" flag will end the transcoding when any stream has reached its end...

The "-vframes 64" flag will encode exactly 64 frames and then exit - unless it cannot encode that many frames and then it will hang forever... (This was actually my clue to your problem.)

Finally, you called the redimensioning too soon and therefore the video was not scaled. (-s 1360x768)